Is it possible in Org-mode to disable the jump to tags upon entering a space at the end of a heading?
In Org-mode, I have the tags right next to the heading text, separated by a single space (i.e. org-tags-column = 0). Now, if I have a heading with existing tags, and I place the cursor at the end of the heading text and press space to enter some more of it, no space is entered, and the cursor just moves to before the colon in tags instead. As a result, not only do I have to enter the space again at the end, but my text is smushed right into the tags all that time, and the highlighting of the tags is botched in the meanwhile, flickering between highlighted and non-highlighted. This is all very jarring, and repeats every time I edit any of the headings at the end—exacerbated by the fact that I use lots and lots of headings.
Obviously, this is some dubious magic specifically done by Org-mode. The question is, is it possible to turn this misfeature off, so I can edit my text normally by entering a character and having it be right there in the text?
I'm currently on Emacs 29.2, mingw32 build on Windows. However, the behavior was the same on MacOS since Emacs 27-something, with which I started. I'm using Doom Emacs, but disabling all the configuration with emacs -q doesn't solve this.

I cannot reproduce this, but I have my org-tags-column set to -120 which, because it's negative,  keeps tags aligned flush right. Read the doc string of the variable (C-h v org-tags-column) and play with to see if you can find a behavior you  like better. But you should at least report the value that you use: edit your question and add that tidbit of information.

Also, does it happen if you start with emacs -q? If not, then something in your init file is causing it.

@NickD As mentioned, I have the tags right after the text of the heading, which is enabled by org-tags-column being 0, and which is how I prefer it. You're right that I should've mentioned whether the configuration affects the behavior: I use Doom Emacs, but the behavior is present with emacs -q.

Strictly, the answer to you question is "no": org-self-insert-command does the insertion and then calls org-fix-tags-on-the-fly. I don't see any way to change the behavior from the  outside. You might want to send a bug report (or RFE) to the Org mode mailing list.

@NickD Thanks for the info!
